# 404 error on file upload

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I have installed the php files of jQuery-file-upload on my server.
All files are stored on xyz.com/blabla/plugins/jQuery-file-upload/

When I try basic.html, I modify as follow and it works :

```
var url = window.location.hostname === 'xyz.com/blabla/' ?
            '//xyz.com/blabla/plugins/jQuery-file-upload/' : 'server/php/';
```

Then I try to integrate it to my main page :

```
xyz.com/blabla/index.php
```

Initialisation is ok, but when I upload files I always get a POST 404 error returning the following path :

```
xyz.com/blabla/server/php/
```

I have tried creating the following folders :

```
server server/php/ server/php/files/
```

Still 404 error... Can't find why

**UPDATE**: After a few tests I figured out that the problem comes from the location of the js and php files.
For ex if the js/css/other folders are in the same folder as html file containing the uploader, then it works. If I upload all jQuery-file-upload folders to a different folder (for ex plugins/...), then I get the 404 error. So I guess some links in the functions are hard coded and not relative. But can't find where.

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Comment: Have you looked at what the `hostname` is at run time?

Comment: window.location.hostname returns www.xyz.com

Comment: Can you post or link to a more complete copy of the code? It would be useful to see how `url` is used.

Comment: I can't, but I've made a new test, I've simply copied the code of basic.html into a file named test.html. Basic is in xyz.com/blabla/plugins/jQuery-file-upload/ and test in xyz.com/blabla/
I've updated the link to js files, and I get the same 404 error.